# PHP Search Array Question

Tags: php, arrays

I need to have an `array_search` search my array strictly making sure that the item is **identical** (meaning the whole thing is the same thing as the input value). I know about the third variable in a `array_search()` function in PHP - the Strict one, but I don't want it to check if its the same instance, as it is not. How would I do this?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
array_search(some, array(someItem,anothervariable, yetanothervariable, some)); 
//output - 0 (the first item) which contains some but isn't exactly some.
```

Requested output:

Instead of outputting the first item that contains some, someItem, it would output the key for the last item, 3, that is the exact search value.

Comment: This IS a repost, but I deleted the old one, as you guys had thumbs downed it three times because I had said something offensive to you. I have reposted it fixed because I think the -3 rating would have screwed my chances of actually getting a legitimate answer for a perfectly proper question.

Comment: When you get -3 votes, it is *not* a "perfectly proper question".

Comment: -1, your code isn't valid PHP. Please post the code you're actually using, as issues with code generally have to do with the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you open to using a foreach loop instead of array_search?**

If so try this:

```
$haystack = array('something', 'someone', 'somewhere', 'some');
$needle = 'some';

foreach($haystack as $key=>$straw){
    if($straw === $needle){
        $straws[$key] = $straw;
        }
    }

print_r($straws);
```

it will print

```
Array ( [3] => some )
```

**Or you could use [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the search value specified.**

Then, using the same $haystack and $needle above:

```
$result = array_keys($haystack,$needle,TRUE);
print_r($result);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 )
```

The first argument is the array to return keys from, The second arg is the search value, if you include this arg, then only keys from array elements that match the search value are returned.  Including the third boolean arg tells the function to use match type as well (===).

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that, but it just seems really inefficient. I guess I might just have to go with that... Thanks.

Comment: Christian, I edited my answer to include a suggestion to use array_keys with an optional search parameter included.  It might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Array search with strict is equivalent to the === operator.

Array search without strict is equivalent to the == operator.

If you need some sort of special comparison that isn't covered by either of them (comparing elements of objects for example) then you need to write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking but in PHP strict comparison is achieved with the 
triple equal sign (===).  This means that both the value and the type must be the same.
So if you compare a string "1" and an integer 1 with === it will fail.
If strict is false then comparing string "1" with integer 1 would succeed.
This is the meaning of strict in the array_search case.
I implemented array_search below so you can see what it is doing.

```
function my_array_search($input, $search_array, $strict=false) {
        if(is_array($search_array)) {
            foreach($search_array as $key => $val) {
                if($strict === true) {
                    if($val === $input) {
                        return $key;
                    }
                } else {
                    if($val == $input) {
                        return $key;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: The weird thing is when I do an array search - as I showed in my question - it comes out with the first item that CONTAINS that string, not the item that IS that string. Falla?

Comment: the code you posted has no dollar sign prefixed to variable names...and if they are strings they should be in double quotes

Comment: Yes I understand that but that was just because it was a demo piece of code showing the concept. In an actual code sample those elements would be there.

Comment: Oh yea like in reality and stuff.